# Proof on why solution to a linear system Ax=b belong to the set of initial abitrary guess plus the Krylov subspace of the matrix & intitial residual?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, dense-subspaces

The below is the digested summary of the Krylov properties section from [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Computational-Linear-Algebra-Nassif/dp/1482258692) book. My question is about the conclusion presented at the end.

By applying the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we can derive that

$$
A^{-1}y = -\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_{i+1}A^iy
$$

Now, assuming $|A| \ne 0$, let $x = A^{-1}b$ be the solution to the linear system $Ax = b$.

Let $x^{(0)}$ be any arbitrary vector. We define $e^{(0)} = x - x^{(0)}$, and $r^{(0)} = b - Ax^{(0)} = Ae^{(0)}$. Substituting $y = r^{(0)}$ in the above equation, we have

$$
e^{(0)} = A^{-1}r^{(0)} = -\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_{i+1}A^ir^{(0)}
$$

I understand everything thus far. However, the next part confuses me, wherein the authors state:

> We conclude that:
> $$
> A^{-1}b \in x^{(0)} + \mathcal{K}_n(A,r^{(0)})
> $$
> where
> $$
> \mathcal{K}_n(A,r^{(0)}) = \text{span}(r^{(0)}, Ar^{(0)}, A^2r^{(0)}, \dots, A^{n-1}r^{(0)})
> $$
> is the $n^\text{th}$ Krylov subspace associated to $A$ and $r^{(0)}$.
> $$

I just do not understand the last part of the derivation i.e. how did they come to this conclusion? Shall appreciate a bit more details explaining this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've said you understand, you've got
\begin{align}
A^{-1}b&=x\\
&=x^{(0)}+e^{(0)}\\
&=x^{(0)}-\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_{i+1}A^ir^{(0)}\\
&\in x^{(0)}+\text{span}(r^{(0)}, Ar^{(0)}, A^2r^{(0)}, \dots, A^{n-1}r^{(0)})\ .
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. So, the **span** aspect arises because $\frac{-c_{i+1}}{|A|}$ is another set of arbitrary constants, say $\alpha_{i+1}$, and hence the second term by definition is the span of these vectors, right?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.